# python desktop app with flask unable to execute multiple thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

i'm making a very small application in python that listen with flask to an endpoint and write to a file the post body, while having a systray icon that i can interact with, now everything is ok but i would like to use a different wsgi server because the included is not recommended for production, but now i have an issue, the thing is now i run flask as a thread so i can continue to execute the rest of the app and having the icon, i've tried with waitress or gevent but i don't know how to run those as a thread
here is the code, do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS
import pystray
from PIL import Image
import threading
import json
import sys
import os
import datetime
from plyer import notification
#from waitress import serve
#from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

appName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]).split(".")[0]

try:
   with open("config.json", "r") as jsonfile:
       datacfg = json.load(jsonfile)  # Reading the file
       print("Read config successful")
       jsonfile.close()
except:
   print("errore lettura configurazione")
   sys.exit(0)

class config:
   hostip = "0.0.0.0"
   hostport = "8080"
   separatorepath = "/"

   csvpath = datacfg["csvpath"]


image = Image.open("scanning.png")

def after_click(icon, query):
   if str(query) == "Apri cartella":
       print("open folder  "+os.name)
       if os.name == 'nt':
           os.startfile(config.csvpath)
   elif str(query) == "Chiudi":
       icon.stop()

icon = pystray.Icon("ABA", image, "app", menu=pystray.Menu(
   pystray.MenuItem("Apri cartella", after_click),
   pystray.MenuItem("Chiudi", after_click)))

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)
flask_thread_kwargs = { 'host': config.hostip, 'port': config.hostport, 'threaded': True, 'use_reloader': False, 'debug': False }

class Post(Resource):
   def post(self):
       parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  # initialize
       parser.add_argument('data', required=True)  # add args
       args = parser.parse_args()  # parse arguments to dictionary
       lista = json.loads(args['data'])
       filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+".dat"
       f = open(config.csvpath+config.separatorepath+filename, "a")

       for el in lista:
           f.write(el+"\n")

       f.close()
       notification.notify(
           title = 'Ricezione',
           message = 'ricevuto post',
           app_icon = None,
           timeout = 10,
       )
       return {}, 200  # return data with 200 OK

api.add_resource(Post, '/post')  # add endpoints

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
       flask_thread = threading.Thread( target = app.run, daemon = True, kwargs = flask_thread_kwargs ).start()
       icon.run()
   finally:
       print( 'end' )
```

Comment: you should probaly run the icon.run() in a thread not the other way around